# Is there is any better alternative for QLVideo to display thumbnails for .avi, .mkv, .webm files on Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, video, quicklook

I've recently downloaded and tested [QLVideo](https://github.com/Marginal/QLVideo) but seems it take ages to generate thumbnails. I have lots of videos on a 2TB hard disk and  it struggles a lot. It is nowhere near as fast as the default Mac QuickLook; not even close! So, it is pretty much unusable.

My macOS version is 12.6.3 and I don't think I've problem with using the App itself but I'm open to suggestions. But please don't ask for very basic stuff like if I relaunched the Finder, refreshed the app or installed it correctly,  etc.

Comment: “Silly stuff” and “I tried everything” need to be clarified.  Potential answerers to your question get frustrated when they take to write something only to be given a response that you don’t like or already attempted. Help us help you by providing some detail about what you tried and what failed thus far.